# Cassandra selective copy

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I want to copy selected rows from a columnfamily to a .csv file. The copy command is available just to dump a column or entire table to a file without where clause. Is there a way to use where clause in copy command?

Another way I thought of was,

Do "Insert into table2 () values ( `select * from table1 where <where_clause>`);" and then dump the table2 to .csv , which is also not possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There are no way to make a where clause in copy, but you can use this method :

echo "select c1,c2.... FROM keySpace.Table where ;" | bin/cqlsh > output.csv

It allows you to save your result in the output.csv file.

Comment: It only outputs 100 rows. And as a text table, not in csv format.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no built-in support for a "where" clause when exporting to a CSV file.

One alternative would be to write your own script using one of the [drivers](https://github.com/datastax). In the script you would do the "select", then read the results and write out to a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to run the SQL with filter and redirect the response to csv

1) Inside the cqlsh, use the CAPTURE command and redirect the output to a file. You need to set the tracing on before executing the command

Example: CAPTURE 'output.txt' -- output of the sql executed after this command gets captured into output.txt file

2) In case if you would like to redirect the SQL output to a file from outside of cqlsh

```
./cqlsh -e'select * from keyspaceName.tableName' > fileName.txt -- hostname
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Amine CHERIFI's answer:

`| sed -e 's/^\s+//; s_\s*\|\s*_,_g; /^-{3,}|^$|^\(.+\)$/d'`

1. Removes spaces
2. Replaces `|` with `,`
3. Removes header separator, empty and summary lines