# Cassandra : COPY data with cql function on column

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to export and import data from a cassandra table for changing a timestamp column to unixepoch column ( ie type timestamp to bigint)

I tried exporting data to csv using below command

```
COPY raw_data(raw_data_field_id, toUnixTimestamp(dt_timestamp), value) TO 'raw_data_3_feb_19.csv' WITH PAGETIMEOUT=40 AND PAGESIZE=20;
```

but getting error as : `Improper COPY command.`

How can I fix this issue or is there a better way to achieve this?

from

```
 raw_data_field_id | dt_timestamp                    | value
-------------------+---------------------------------+-------
                23 | 2018-06-12 07:15:00.656000+0000 | 131.3
```

to

```
 raw_data_field_id | dt_unix_timestamp_epoch         | value
-------------------+---------------------------------+-------
                23 | 1528787700656                   | 131.3
```

Answer (score 3):

The `COPY` command does not support adding extra functions to process the output.

I would say you have several solutions:

- export the data in csv using COPY, convert the timestamp value (using sh commands or a high level language) and import it to a new table
- export using  `echo "select raw_data_field_id, toUnixTimestamp(dt_timestamp), value from raw.raw_data;" | ccm node1 cqlsh > output.csv`, change the csv so it has a proper format and import it to a new table (this solution is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29675841/8356801))
- write your own conversion tool using one of Cassandra drivers (python, java etc).
- maybe you could try something with a UDF, but I haven't tested this.

You should be aware that `COPY FROM` supports datasets that have less than 2 milion rows.