# How to export data in a specified time to csv with cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I can use this command to export all the data to csv:

```
COPY data  TO '/usr/local/cassandra/my_data.csv';
```

But now I want to export the data of the specified time to csv, such as this condition:

```
select * from data where upload_time >='2020-10-16 00:00:00.000+00' and upload_time <'2020-10-17 00:00:00.000+0000' allow filtering ;
```

What should I do with command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cassandra selective copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452158/cassandra-selective-copy)

Comment: Hi,I saw this question,but there is something wrong when I do it with echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DSBulk utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) with custom query, but you need to be careful and put the optimized condition so it will perform full scan, but using the token ranges (see [this blog post for details](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading)).

Something like (replace `pk` with the name of the actual partition key column, and unsplit query string - I split it just for readability):

```
dsbulk unload -url data.csv \
-query "SELECT * FROM ks.table WHERE token(pk) > :start AND token(pk) <= :end 
  AND upload_time >='2020-01-01 00:00:00.000+00' 
  AND upload_time <'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000' allow filtering"
```

Another way is to use Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) (even in the local master mode) - it will do the same under the hood, something like this (example for `spark-shell` in Scala, could be done similarly via [pyspark](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md)):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("table", "keyspace").load()
val filtered = data.filter("upload_time >= cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00.000+00' as timestamp) AND upload_time <= cast('2021-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000' as timestamp)")
filtered.write.format("csv").save("data.csv")
```