# Cassandra copy n rows from one table and insert them to another table

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I need to copy the first 100k records from "prod" keyspace to "test" keyspace in Cassandra, I tried to use dsbulk but it export the whole table data and it is taking longer time.

Is there any solution to fetch 100k records from one table and copy them into another table in Cassandra?

Comment: See the answer on this thread discussion about COPY command:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452158/cassandra-selective-copy

Comment: Did you try the option -query from DSBULK ? dsbulk unload -query "SELECT .... LIMIT ...;"

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkUnload.html

Comment: The query unload with url parameter worked,

Answer (score 0):

Download/ install [dsbulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/install/dsbulkInstall.html#dsbulkPostInstallRequirementsAndRecommendations) dsbulk package and update the variable $PATH value with dsbulk bin folder and then update the ./.bashrc file.

Then use the below command to unload the data from the table to csv file

`dsbulk unload -url /tmp/export/ -query "SELECT * from prod.user LIMIT 100000"`